# Fedex PHP API Integration for indian address

Tags: xml, api, fedex

Does anyone integrated fedex API in PHP to generate tracking numbers and shipping label? I am submitting below XML to fedex -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:m0="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v19">

<SOAP-ENV:Body>

<ProcessShipmentRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v19">

<WebAuthenticationDetail>

<UserCredential>

<Key>avpSZAQRg9gu3zfm</Key>

<Password>gSmYLbjJwCYYVsoIwfp2ux2FY</Password>

</UserCredential>

</WebAuthenticationDetail>

<ClientDetail>

<AccountNumber>604794161</AccountNumber>

<MeterNumber>100339204</MeterNumber>

</ClientDetail>

<TransactionDetail>

<CustomerTransactionId>8787</CustomerTransactionId>

</TransactionDetail>

<Version>

<ServiceId>ship</ServiceId>

<Major>19</Major>

<Intermediate>0</Intermediate>

<Minor>0</Minor>

</Version>

<RequestedShipment>

<ShipTimestamp>2017-07-29T12:34:56-06:00</ShipTimestamp>

<DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType>

<ServiceType>STANDARD_OVERNIGHT</ServiceType>

<PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</PackagingType>

<Shipper>

<Contact>

<PersonName>Piyush Rana</PersonName>

<CompanyName>Eclators</CompanyName>

<PhoneNumber>9925383633</PhoneNumber>

<EMailAddress>rana@gmail.com</EMailAddress>

</Contact>

<Address>

<StreetLines>14-B-5</StreetLines>

<StreetLines>DkPark</StreetLines>

<City>Surat</City>

<StateOrProvinceCode>Gujarat</StateOrProvinceCode>

<PostalCode>395007</PostalCode>

<CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>

</Address>

</Shipper>

<Recipient>

<Contact>

<PersonName>Panakj Rana</PersonName>

<CompanyName>pp</CompanyName>

<PhoneNumber>9252905058</PhoneNumber>

<EMailAddress>php.pankaj@gmail.com</EMailAddress>

</Contact>

<Address>

<StreetLines>Near yadav floor mill</StreetLines>

<StreetLines>sarvodaya basti</StreetLines>

<City>Bikaner</City>

<StateOrProvinceCode>rajasthan</StateOrProvinceCode>

<PostalCode>334004</PostalCode>

<CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>

</Address>

</Recipient>

<ShippingChargesPayment>

<PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>

<Payor>

<ResponsibleParty>

<AccountNumber>604794161</AccountNumber>

<Contact>

<ContactId>12345</ContactId>

<PersonName>shanu rana</PersonName>

</Contact>

</ResponsibleParty>

</Payor>

</ShippingChargesPayment>

<SpecialServicesRequested>

<SpecialServiceTypes>ELECTRONIC_TRADE_DOCUMENTS</SpecialServiceTypes>

</SpecialServicesRequested>

<CustomsClearanceDetail>

<DutiesPayment>

<PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>

<Payor>

<ResponsibleParty>

<AccountNumber>604794161</AccountNumber>

<Contact>

<ContactId>12345</ContactId>

<PersonName>Input Your Information</PersonName>

</Contact>

</ResponsibleParty>

</Payor>

</DutiesPayment>

<DocumentContent>DOCUMENTS_ONLY</DocumentContent>

<CustomsValue>

<Currency>INR</Currency>

<Amount>100.00</Amount>

</CustomsValue>

<Commodities>

<NumberOfPieces>1</NumberOfPieces>

<Description>ABCD</Description>

<CountryOfManufacture>US</CountryOfManufacture>

<Weight>

<Units>LB</Units>

<Value>1.0</Value>

</Weight>

<Quantity>1</Quantity>

<QuantityUnits>cm</QuantityUnits>

<UnitPrice>

<Currency>INR</Currency>

<Amount>1.000000</Amount>

</UnitPrice>

<CustomsValue>

<Currency>INR</Currency>

<Amount>100.000000</Amount>

</CustomsValue>

</Commodities>

<ExportDetail>

<ExportComplianceStatement>30.37(f)</ExportComplianceStatement>

</ExportDetail>

</CustomsClearanceDetail>

<LabelSpecification>

<LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</LabelFormatType>

<ImageType>PNG</ImageType>

<LabelStockType>PAPER_7X4.75</LabelStockType>

</LabelSpecification>

<ShippingDocumentSpecification>

<ShippingDocumentTypes>COMMERCIAL_INVOICE</ShippingDocumentTypes>

<CommercialInvoiceDetail>

<Format>

<ImageType>PDF</ImageType>

<StockType>PAPER_LETTER</StockType>

<ProvideInstructions>1</ProvideInstructions>

</Format>

</CommercialInvoiceDetail>

</ShippingDocumentSpecification>

<RateRequestTypes>LIST</RateRequestTypes>

<PackageCount>1</PackageCount>

<RequestedPackageLineItems>

<SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>

<Weight>

<Units>LB</Units>

<Value>20.0</Value>

</Weight>

<Dimensions>

<Length>12</Length>

<Width>12</Width>

<Height>12</Height>

<Units>IN</Units>

</Dimensions>

<CustomerReferences>

<CustomerReferenceType>CUSTOMER_REFERENCE</CustomerReferenceType>

<Value>TC001_01_PT1_ST01_PK01_SNDUS_RCPCA_POS</Value>

</CustomerReferences>

</RequestedPackageLineItems>

</RequestedShipment>

</ProcessShipmentRequest>

</SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But getting below output -

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [xmlnsSOAPENV] => http//schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
        )

```
[SOAPENVHeader] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[SOAPENVBody] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [ProcessShipmentReply] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [HighestSeverity] => ERROR
                [Notifications] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [Severity] => ERROR
                        [Source] => ship
                        [Code] => 2200
                        [Message] => Missing or Invalid Shipment purpose for Commercial Invoice
                        [LocalizedMessage] => Missing or Invalid Shipment purpose for Commercial Invoice
                    )

                [TransactionDetail] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [CustomerTransactionId] => 8787
                    )

                [Version] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [ServiceId] => ship
                        [Major] => 19
                        [Intermediate] => 0
                        [Minor] => 0
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

What is the issue with this api? Please suggest. Or if anyone already integrated then please provide us the code snippet which i can use to generate fedex tracking number and shipping label.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your API credentials immediately. You just pasted them here for all to see.

You are missing the `Purpose` tag:

```
<CommercialInvoice>
  <Purpose>SOLD</Purpose>
</CommercialInvoice>
```

Possible values:

- GIFT
- SOLD
- NOT_SOLD
- PERSONAL_EFFECTS
- REPAIR_AND_RETURN
- SAMPLE

Here is a complete working example from [RocketShipIt](https://www.rocketship.it/) (I am the lead developer):

```
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <ProcessShipmentRequest>
      <WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <UserCredential>
          <Key></Key>
          <Password></Password>
        </UserCredential>
      </WebAuthenticationDetail>
      <ClientDetail>
        <AccountNumber></AccountNumber>
        <MeterNumber></MeterNumber>
      </ClientDetail>
      <Version>
        <ServiceId>ship</ServiceId>
        <Major>17</Major>
        <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
        <Minor>0</Minor>
      </Version>
      <RequestedShipment>
        <ShipTimestamp>2017-07-29T07:52:19.692709183-07:00</ShipTimestamp>
        <DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType>
        <ServiceType>STANDARD_OVERNIGHT</ServiceType>
        <PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</PackagingType>
        <TotalWeight>
          <Units>LB</Units>
          <Value>5</Value>
        </TotalWeight>
        <Shipper>
          <Contact>
            <PersonName>John Doe</PersonName>
            <CompanyName>John Doe</CompanyName>
            <PhoneNumber>1231231234</PhoneNumber>
          </Contact>
          <Address>
            <StreetLines>2000 Meadowvale Rd</StreetLines>
            <City>mumbai</City>
            <StateOrProvinceCode>MH</StateOrProvinceCode>
            <PostalCode>400037</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>
          </Address>
        </Shipper>
        <Recipient>
          <Contact>
            <PersonName>John Doe</PersonName>
            <PhoneNumber>1231231234</PhoneNumber>
          </Contact>
          <Address>
            <StreetLines>2300 Southern Blvd</StreetLines>
            <City>Mumbai</City>
            <StateOrProvinceCode>MH</StateOrProvinceCode>
            <PostalCode>400037</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>
          </Address>
        </Recipient>
        <ShippingChargesPayment>
          <PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>
          <Payor>
            <ResponsibleParty>
              <AccountNumber></AccountNumber>
              <Contact>
                <CompanyName>John Doe</CompanyName>
              </Contact>
              <Address>
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
              </Address>
            </ResponsibleParty>
          </Payor>
        </ShippingChargesPayment>
        <SpecialServicesRequested>
          <SpecialServiceTypes>COD</SpecialServiceTypes>
          <CodDetail>
            <CodCollectionAmount>
              <Currency>INR</Currency>
              <Amount>100</Amount>
            </CodCollectionAmount>
            <CollectionType>CASH</CollectionType>
          </CodDetail>
        </SpecialServicesRequested>
        <CustomsClearanceDetail>
          <DutiesPayment>
            <PaymentType>RECIPIENT</PaymentType>
          </DutiesPayment>
          <CustomsValue>
            <Currency>INR</Currency>
            <Amount>0</Amount>
          </CustomsValue>
          <CommercialInvoice>
            <Purpose>SOLD</Purpose>
          </CommercialInvoice>
          <Commodities>
            <NumberOfPieces>1</NumberOfPieces>
            <Description>My Description</Description>
            <CountryOfManufacture>US</CountryOfManufacture>
            <Weight>
              <Units>LB</Units>
              <Value>2.5</Value>
            </Weight>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <QuantityUnits>EA</QuantityUnits>
            <UnitPrice>
              <Currency>INR</Currency>
              <Amount>50</Amount>
            </UnitPrice>
          </Commodities>
        </CustomsClearanceDetail>
        <LabelSpecification>
          <LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</LabelFormatType>
          <ImageType>PNG</ImageType>
          <LabelStockType>PAPER_4X6</LabelStockType>
          <LabelPrintingOrientation>TOP_EDGE_OF_TEXT_FIRST</LabelPrintingOrientation>
        </LabelSpecification>
        <PackageCount>1</PackageCount>
        <RequestedPackageLineItems>
          <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
          <GroupPackageCount>1</GroupPackageCount>
          <Weight>
            <Units>LB</Units>
            <Value>5</Value>
          </Weight>
          <Dimensions>
            <Length>1</Length>
            <Width>1</Width>
            <Height>1</Height>
            <Units>IN</Units>
          </Dimensions>
        </RequestedPackageLineItems>
      </RequestedShipment>
    </ProcessShipmentRequest>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: Hey sanbornm thanks for feedback.  But still it give us an error. Can you please create one test file for us with complete code including curl? So that we can test and may be we are not integrating it in a correct way? Your help  deeply appreciated brother.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have the wrong structure of sending the request. You should add `CommercialInvoice` under `CustomsClearanceDetail`. This error is occurring due to wrong placement of request parameters in the request.